# How do I make the "create option" feature onblur in chosen plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Koenpunt's fork](https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/blob/option_adding/chosen/chosen.jquery.js) of chosen, which allows me to use the "create_option" option in the config object.

It provides a neat way for users to create elements when it's not available in the select box.

Right now it works by making the user click on the 'create new thing' link which appears in the box, but I'd like it to create these new options automatically. Is this possible? Is there an event I should trigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding,

1. You're trying to add options dynamically while typing it in the SearchBox.
2. Koenpunt's fork of `Chosen.jquery.js` has this ability only by clicking the Add Option link.

Let me keep it simple, **triggering Add Option link via key event**(eg: enter key) will be better.  After a long multiple tries I found the opt method from `chosen.js`

```
Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker = function(evt){
...
...
}
```

Add the below script in you html file after intializing the `jQuery` and **Koenpunt's fork** of `Chosen.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker = function(evt) {
       if( event.which === 13)  {   
        $(this.form_field).append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
        $(this.form_field).trigger('liszt:updated');
        this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
        return this.result_select(evt);
       }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to create a JSFiddle, hope will get it.

**EDIT1:** Atlast I got it in [JSFIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/3HFh9/1/)

**EDIT2:** While trying to find a way for `onBlur()`, I got the following opt method

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.input_blur = function(evt){
...
...
}
```

Little change in the above code:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.input_blur = function(evt) {
        $(this.form_field).append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
        $(this.form_field).trigger('liszt:updated');
        this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
        return this.result_select(evt);
    }
```

Corresponding [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/3HFh9/2/)  Hope you can find the differences in both the fiddles.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can adapt this to the tagging fields (multiple select) using your code, thank you for the extensive help.

Comment: @adityamenon  I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/), it has the exact functionality that you're looking for (i.e. creating an option on-blur).

[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select-2.1.html) is also another alternative, it also has the same tagging functionality that you expect (see the "Tagging Support" section at the bottom of the demo).

Edit: Added Select2

Comment: `Select2` functions perfectly like I need, plus the looks are exactly like 'chosen'. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.